# subl working in Terminal but not as default editor in git

Tags: bash, git, sublimetext

Trying to set Sublime as the default editor in git.

`git config --list` returns

```
core.editor=subl -n -w
push.default=upstream
merge.conflictstyle=diff3
```

`subl .bash_profile` open this file in Sublime

```
# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

However, when I run `git pull origin master` it returns

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

Why does it say the command is not found when the command is working?

EDIT: I'm running macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3

Comment: Hello,

I'm not an user of Sublime Text but I've found this line in the documentation : 

"Reading from standard input only works in OS X."

Which OS are you running ? Can it be related ?

Comment: Thank you, added info to the post.

Comment: @mcansado Did you try `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the output of `git config --list` above

Comment: @mcansado I'm not sure you need the alias in your `.bash_profile`. Try to set the full path of `subl`: `/usr/local/bin/subl` (run `which subl` to verify).

Comment: That's not where Sublime is. This is a work laptop so Sublime is not installed in that path.
Running `which subl` returns nothing which is odd because `subl` opens Sublime.

Comment: Try to provide the full path to Sublime that's configured in your bash profile: `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192272/discussion-between-mcansado-and-maroun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running Sublime via its full path works, providing the same path for `core.editor` should also work. Try the following:

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```